# Make use of encrypted or anonymous data in database

Tags: encryption, authentication, user-management

As an answer to the following question, I read the idea of encrypting user data with 2 keys based on random generation and the user password:
[Store encrypted user data in database](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157422/store-encrypted-user-data-in-database)

But could anyone explain what would happen if the user password is reset? Would all data previously encrypted be lost?

Or how to prevent the user from losing access to data? But keeps it encrypted in the database?